# Is this 2 router setup double NAT?

Tags: networking, router, dhcp, nat

I have one router connected via the WAN port to the internet it is doing DHCP and its address is 172.16.0.1, gives out address 172.16.0.2 - 172.16.0.100.

Now a second router is connected by a cable to its WAN port. This router has DHCP on, its IP address is 172.16.0.101 and is giving IP addresses out between 172.16.0.102 - 172.16.0.200.

I can't set this secound router to bridge mode or disable any NAT setting so is this a double NAT scenario and will it cause me troubles? I also tried disabling DHCP on the 2nd router but didn't seem like the connected devices were getting IP addresses.

Comment: Why is the second router connected by a cable to its WAN port when it's not connected to the WAN?

Comment: ..because the 2nd router can't receive internet through its LAN ports.

Comment: Since it's not actually doing any routing, that doesn't matter.